# Android: how to make a view grow to fill available space?

Tags: android, android-layout

This seems straightforward, but I can't figure out how to do it.  I have a horizontal layout with an EditText and two ImageButtons.  I want the ImageButtons to be of a fixed size, and the EditText to take up the remaining space in the layout.  How can this be accomplished?

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </EditText>
        <ImageButton 
            android:src="@drawable/img1"
            android:layout_width="50dip" 
            android:layout_height="50dip">
        </ImageButton>
        <ImageButton 
            android:src="@drawable/img2"
            android:layout_width="50dip" 
            android:layout_height="50dip">
        </ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

try this in relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dip" 
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dip" 
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn1"/>
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn2">
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works great. (Except that the ImageButtons must be defined before the EditText, as Joseph noted).

Comment: fill_parent - This constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by {@code match_parent}.

Answer (score 166):

If you want to keep the layout the same (ie, buttons after the text), use the `layout_weight` property, along with `fill_parent`, thus:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </EditText>
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@drawable/img1"
        android:layout_width="50dip" 
        android:layout_height="50dip">
    </ImageButton>
    <ImageButton 
        android:src="@drawable/img2"
        android:layout_width="50dip" 
        android:layout_height="50dip">
    </ImageButton>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Giving the `EditText` 'weight' makes it get figured out last and gives precedence to the buttons. Play with the different layout_weights and see how much fun you can have!

Comment: Thank you. I have in my layout 3 areas (headers, content- WebView and footer) it solved the problem by setting the WebView layout_weight = 1 and footer's layout_weight = 0.

Comment: Didn't know the trick with setting weight and 0dp to just one child.. Thank you!

Comment: is this generally considered best practices? It's interesting that you can influence the order in which android resolves the views.

Comment: width should be kept 0 I think

Answer (score 25):

Use set the `layout_width` or `layout_height` to `0dp` (By the orientation you want to fill remaining space).
Then use the `layout_weight` to make it fill remaining space.

Answer (score 21):

Okay:

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:src="@drawable/img1"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
            android:layout_height="50dip">
        </ImageButton>
        <ImageButton 
            android:src="@drawable/img2"
            android:layout_width="50dip" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
            android:layout_height="50dip">
        </ImageButton>
        <EditText 
            android:layout_below="@id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The key points of the layout are:

- The items with fixed sized are placed first in the layout, this way when Android comes to calculating the height of the height of things with `fill_parent` later in the file it only takes into account the remaining space, not all of the space it could possibly occupy if nothing else was there
- The EditText has a height of `fill_parent` (`match_parent` in 2.2+) so that it takes up the rest of the available space

Sorry didn't read your question will enough. The above code provides the answer if you want to do it in a vertical fashion. For a horizontal layout the code posted by @Sunil should work.

Comment: Thank you Joseph. This does work.  Though, I gave credit to Sunil for being slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem filling a LinearLayout (I´m working with Artic Fox version). In my design, I have 2 buttons in a LinearLayout with vertical orientation. In my case I solve the problem by putting:

```
android:insetBottom="0dp"
android:insetTop="0dp"
```