# how to I set the height to fit the whole screen?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following activity

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato"
    android:text="Home"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/featured_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/cerapro"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="20dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/featured_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="167dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/featured_title"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[0]" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="248dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/featured_image"
    />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

How do I set the recycleView height so that it fits the remainder of the screen after the navigation view is drawn?

Also how do I make sure the bottom nav view is always at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the best solution is to use **height = 0** for recycler view. do:

1- To ensure that bottom nav is always at the bottom:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

2- to ensure your recycleView fill remaining part of screen down there, use:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/featured_image"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
```

to sum up 
your code should be this:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/featured_image"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `LinearLayout` with `vertical` orientation, then make all other views' height `wrap_content` and use `layout_height="0dp"` `layout_weight="1"` on the view that you want to fill the screen with.

Example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5407124